# Replace the value of third column if the first two columns are same in two variables

Tags: awk

I need to replace the value of the third column if the first two columns are same in two variables.

I tried: to store the first and second column of the first variable using `NR===FNR`. Then if first and second columns are same then
replace the column three of variable "b" with third column of variable "s". However, doing  `$3=$3` does not make any sense.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$1FS$2;next} $1FS$2 in a {$3=$3}1' <(echo "$s") <(echo "$b")
NODE AREA-29 1 UP ENABLED PINGABLE ASIA ACTIVE
NODE AREA-21 1 UP ENABLED PINGABLE ASIA ACTIVE
NODE AREA-20 1 UP ENABLED PINGABLE ASIA ACTIVE


echo "$b"
NODE  AREA-29  1   UP   ENABLED     PINGABLE  ASIA                   ACTIVE
NODE  AREA-21  1   UP   ENABLED     PINGABLE  ASIA                   ACTIVE
NODE  AREA-20  1   UP   ENABLED     PINGABLE  ASIA                   ACTIVE


echo "$s"
NODE  AREA-21   2
NODE  AREA-29   10
NODE  AREA-20   1
```

## desired result:

```
NODE  AREA-29  10  UP   ENABLED     PINGABLE  ASIA                   ACTIVE
NODE  AREA-21  2   UP   ENABLED     PINGABLE  ASIA                   ACTIVE
NODE  AREA-20  1   UP   ENABLED     PINGABLE  ASIA                   ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{ a[$1,$2]=$3; next }(($1,$2) in a){ $3=a[$1,$2] }1' <(echo "$s") <(echo "$b")
```

The output:

```
NODE    AREA-29 10  UP  ENABLED PINGABLE    ASIA    ACTIVE
NODE    AREA-21 2   UP  ENABLED PINGABLE    ASIA    ACTIVE
NODE    AREA-20 1   UP  ENABLED PINGABLE    ASIA    ACTIVE
```

---

> Standard awk simulates multidimensional arrays by separating subscript
>   values with commas. The values are concatenated into a single string,
>   separated by the value of ***SUBSEP***

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1FS$2]=$3;next}$1FS$2 in a { $3 = a[$1FS$2] }1' <(echo "$s") <(echo "$b")
```

This one just takes $3 as the value stored in array a. Then if a match is found the substitution of $3 takes place.